# Implementing additional standard run rules with R and qcc

Tags: r, statistics, qcc

I am a newbie with R, and would like to understand what it can do for control charting.  I have read articles on qcc and created sample charts in R studio based on my own datasets to generate graphics or simply the underlying data.

It appears that two out of the shewhart control/run rules are implemented in QCC (+/- 3 sigma and a string above/below center), but more have been defined and are frequently used in practice.  [e.g. Nelson rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelson_rules)

Is there an R library/function that implements these?  In addition to implementing the rules, I want to support the option to specify the "constant" related to the rule. For example where the referenced article says "Eight points in a row.."  I would like eight to be a parameter. I'm thinking that the $data output from the qcc command could be passed as an argument (along with vector of rule "constant" options), and in return would be a list of violation points and rule number violated.

Any thoughts / suggestions?

Comment: Well, a suggestion is to use the `ggplot2` package, which gives you a lot more control over your charts.

Comment: Hey Bernardo, Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not really looking for better control over the graphics.  I'm looking specifically for functionality to implement all 8 Nelson/AT&T run rules with parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're working on the implementation of Nelson Rules in R. I think this is exactly what you're looking for (happy to share, I couldn't find an R implementation anywhere else on the internet):

```
nelsonr1 <- function(x, m = mean(x), s = sd(x)) {
    # Nelson's QC rule 1: detect values outside + or -3 sd
    which(abs((x - m) / s) >= 3)
}

nelsonr2 <- function(x, m = mean(x), minrun = 9) {
    # Nelson's QC rule 2: detect runs of >= 9 points on the same side of the mean
    n <- length(x)
    counts <- sign(x - m)
    result <- counts
    for (runlength in 2:minrun)
        result <- result + c(counts[runlength:n], rep(0, runlength - 1))
    which(abs(result) >= minrun)
}

nelsonr3 <- function(x, minrun = 6) {
    # Nelson's QC rule 3: detect strict increase or decrease in >= 6 points in a row
    # Between 6 points you have 5 instances of increasing or decreasing. Therefore minrun - 1.
    n <- length(x)
    signs <- sign(c(x[-1], x[n]) - x)
    counts <- signs
    for (rl in 2:(minrun - 1)) {
        counts <- counts + c(signs[rl:n], rep(0, rl - 1))
    }
    which(abs(counts) >= minrun - 1)
}

nelsonr4 <- function(x, m = mean(x), minrun = 14, directing_from_mean = FALSE) {
    # Nelson's QC rule 4: 14 points in a row alternating in direction from the mean,
    # or 14 points in a row alternating in increase and decrease
    n <- length(x)
    if (directing_from_mean == TRUE) {
        signs <- sign(x - m)
    } else {
        signs <- sign(c(x[-1],x[n]) - x)
    }
    counts <- signs
    fac <- -1
    for (rl in 2:minrun) {
        counts <- counts + fac * c(signs[rl:n], rep(0, rl - 1))
        fac <- -fac
    }
    counts <- abs(counts)
    which(counts >= minrun)
}

nelsonr5 <- function(x, m = mean(x), s = sd(x), minrun = 3) {
    # Nelson's QC rule 5: two out of 3 >2 sd from mean in the same direction
    n <- length(x)
    pos <- 1 * ((x - m) / s > 2)
    neg <- 1 * ((x - m) / s < -2)
    poscounts <- pos
    negcounts <- neg
    for (rl in 2:minrun) {
        poscounts <- poscounts + c(pos[rl:n], rep(0, rl - 1))
        negcounts <- negcounts + c(neg[rl:n], rep(0, rl - 1))
    }
    counts <- apply(cbind(poscounts, negcounts), 1, max)
    which(counts >= minrun -1)
}

nelsonr6 <- function(x, m = mean(x), s = sd(x), minrun = 5) {
    # Nelson's QC rule 6: four out of five > 1 sd from mean in the same direction
    n <- length(x)
    pos <- 1 * ((x - m) / s > 1)
    neg <- 1 * ((x - m) / s < -1)
    poscounts <- pos
    negcounts <- neg
    for (rl in 2:minrun) {
        poscounts <- poscounts + c(pos[rl:n], rep(0, rl - 1))
        negcounts <- negcounts + c(neg[rl:n], rep(0, rl - 1))
    }
    counts <- apply(cbind(poscounts, negcounts), 1, max)
    which(counts >= minrun - 1)
}

nelsonr7 <- function(x, m = mean(x), s = sd(x), minrun = 15) {
    # Nelson's QC rule 7: >= 15 points in a row within 1 sd from the mean
    n <- length(x)
    within <- 1 * (abs((x - m) / s) < 1)
    counts <- within
    for (rl in 2:minrun)
        counts <- counts + c(within[rl:n], rep(0, rl - 1))
    which(counts >= minrun)
}

nelsonr8 <- function(x, m = mean(x), s = sd(x), minrun = 8) {
    # Nelson's QC rule 8: >= 8 points in a row all outside the m + -1s range
    n <- length(x)
    outofrange <- 1 * (abs((x - m) / s) > 1)
    counts <- outofrange
    for (rl in 2:minrun)
        counts <- counts + c(outofrange[rl:n], rep(0, rl - 1))
    which(counts >= minrun)
}
```

> For example where the referenced article says "Eight points in a row.." I would like eight to be a parameter.

That's what this does too with the parameter `minrun` in some functions.

Comment: I actually stopped pursuing R for my purposes after posting the above in part because it didn't support the rules.   This might reopen the option for a future release of my project. One comment about the statistics applied-  I think sd(x) is overall standard deviation of the result set, which is not typically what would be used in a control chart. Instead, if an actual value is not known, a deterministic estimate is made based on  a median or average moving range over some number of preceding points.  The values can be radically different sometimes.  Might be important for your research?

Comment: That's true, and that's why the sd(x) is a parameter. You could use your own s where ever you like. I also use the mean as a parameter, because now it uses the arithmetic mean, but one might use a geometric or harmonic mean for instance. I myself use the EWMA as moving average. I would DEFINITELY get back to R if I were you :) Try RStudio, a really *really* nice way of working with R.

Comment: I *do* think my syntax is the answer to your question though. Please mark it as answer if you think so too. Thanks!